# Update moment.js when React Native App is reopened

Tags: react-native, expo, momentjs

I am not sure that question can be answered in general. I want to update `moment's current date` when my React Native app comes back to foreground.

At the moment, moment does not update when I open the app and reopen it after one day without closing it. So the current date is still set to yesterday.

I know already that I can get the App State like that: https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate.
But I still don't know how to update moment so all my dates are correctly on the next day when the app is reopened.

One possible solution would be to reload the app hard, but I hope there is another way.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you storing the current date using a state variable? If not, then you should so that  in your AppState listener when the nextAppState is active you can change the date variable to the current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tried it using [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) and it works as expected. Here is a quick code snippet.

```js
const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(new Date())

useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", (nextAppState) => {
       if (nextAppState === "active") {
          setCurrentDate(new Date())
       }
    })
    return () => {
        subscription.remove()
    }
}, [setCurrentDate])
```

Everytime the app is reopened from the background `currentDate` is set to `new Date()`, thus the components state changed which causes it to rerender with the new date.